# EntityFramework.Utilities UpdateAll with an byte array (binary(30)) column

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using EF Utilities to do a batch update on the data without retrieving from the database. The following error occurred when the column with the binary(30) (in my case) involved. I have an impression that any columns with Non-Integer datatypes will cause the error. (I tested with DateTime column to update and had no issue.)

Can someone help me how to resolve this issue?

```
var newByteArray = new byte[] {10,20,....};
var datasToUpdate = oldDatasToUpdate.Select( i => new Data { Id = i.Id, MyByteArray = newByteArray });
EFBatchOperations.For(entities, entities.Datas).UpdateAll(datasToUpdate, x => x.ColumnsToUpdate(d => d.MyByteArray));
```

Received an invalid column length from the bcp client for colid1.

Comment: download its source code and debug: `provider.UpdateItems(items, tableMapping.Schema, tableMapping.TableName, properties, connectionToUse, batchSize, spec);` or show error details

Comment: @Dongdong Error I received is this "an invalid column length from the bcp client for colid1"

Comment: change column `binary(30)` to `varbinary(30)`

Comment: it was a typo in my original post. the type was already varbinary(30)

Answer (score 0):

`binary(30)` , `char(30)`, means: data length must be 30. unless special requirement, usually we use `nchar`, `varchar`, `nvarchar`, `varbinary` instead.